# add to jQuery serializearray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have `var data = serializearray()`. 
The output of `data` is

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    value: "3"
  },
 ]
```

How do i add more names and values to data after `serializearray()` has been done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output is just a Javascript array, so you can manipulate it as such.

- To add another element: `data.push({ name: "d", value: "4" });`
- To modify an existing element: `data[0].name = "newName";`

For more information, [see the MDN docs for Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 4):

```
data.push({
    name: 'foo',
    value: 'bar'
});
```

And you even can pass several additional objects in one call:

```
data.push({
    name: 'foo',
    value: 'bar'
}, {
    name: 'baz',
    value: '...'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Push onto the array:

```
data.push({
   name: 'd',
   value: '4'
});
```

Or concat multiple arrays:

```
var newData = [{
   name: 'd',
   value: '4'
}];
data = data.concat(newData);
```